# Binding Text property in ComboBox not working

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, combobox, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application containing several `ComboBoxes`. The `ItemsSource` of some of the comboboxes is bound to a list of objects. I want to bind a text property of each combobox to some property of `MyObject`. Each time a user selects some row in `MyListView`, I update the properties of `MyObject`, and I want the text properties of the comboboxes to update as well.

This is the XAML for one of the comboboxes:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="StackPanel_MyStackPanel">
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_MyComboBox"
              IsEditable="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

In the code behind:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

// On the selection changed event handler of the MyListView,
// I update the MyProperty of the myObject.

this.StackPanel_MyStackPanel.DataContext = myObject;
```

the definition of `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string _MyProperty;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _MyProperty; }
        set { _MyProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

This is not working.... and I don't know why.

Comment: When exactly do you update `myObject.MyProperty`, before or after you assign `this.StackPanel_MyStackPanel.DataContext = myObject`?

Comment: I want to bind the Text property of the comboBox to MyObject.MyProperty , The ItemSource of the ComboBox is binded to some collection in my code behind - I didn't mention here to what collection.

Comment: @Clemens  After  I assign this.StackPanel_MyStackPanel.DataContext = myObject

Comment: Then class `MyObject` needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and raise the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event when `MyProperty` changes.

Comment: O.K.....you are right...I will do it now , and tell you if it solved my problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data class needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx):

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _MyProperty; 
    public string MyProperty
    { 
        get { return _MyProperty;} 
        set
        {
            _MyProperty = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working..

btw, ItemsSource is for the items in the combobox, you don't need to set it here

I added a button for testing it... this is my codebehind:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainView"/> class.
/// </summary>
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    //On the selection changed event handler of the MyListView , I update the 
    //MyProperty of the myObject.

    this.StackPanel_MyStackPanel.DataContext = myObject;

}

private void test_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(myObject.MyProperty);
}
```

My XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel_MyStackPanel"
            Width="Auto"
            Height="Auto"
            Orientation="Vertical">
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_MyComboBox"
              IsEditable="True"
              Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" />
    <Button Name="test" Click="test_Click" Content="Show it" />
</StackPanel>
```

I took your implementation of `MyObject`, but renamed your local variable to `_MyProperty` - it was `MyPropety`